# Vue.js webpack issue - js is not accepted update propagation at hotAppy

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I am using vue, and when i modify the index.js i get an error like below within the browser when HMR is trying to process the change.  Does anyone know why?

```
changeorder.js:476 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Aborted because ./Scripts/app/changeorder/index.js is not accepted
Update propagation: ./Scripts/app/changeorder/index.js -> 0
    at hotApply (changeorder.js:476)
    at replace (hmr.js?797c:60)
```

This error occurs when i modify the input property below..within index.js and then HMR will picks up the change.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';

new Vue({
    el: '#editor',
    data: {
        input: 'hello'
    },
    components: {
      App,
    }
})
```

Comment: Can we also see your code at index.js so we can know how you edit the input property?

Comment: I am editing, changing the property in index.js via IDE and expecting hmr to reload but instead I get that error.  Ty. You can find the code in this https://github.com/dyardyGIT/WebApplication1---webpack-plugin-serve

Comment: Were you able to find the cause of the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to I get hot module reloading to work in a typescript monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091475/how-to-i-get-hot-module-reloading-to-work-in-a-typescript-monorepo)