# How to I get hot module reloading to work in a typescript monorepo

Tags: typescript, webpack, monorepo, hot-module-replacement

So I've been trying for the last few days completely in vain to get hot module reloading working in my Typescript/React/Koa/Mongo based monorepo; I feel like I've been banging my head against a brick wall. The documentation for HMR is pitiful (almost everything on the internet only goes *part* of the way of explaining how to do something). I've done a lot of googling and read lots of different ... similar versions of my problem, but nobody seems to have a useful solution.

I've put together a minimal repo version of the problem: https://github.com/benwainwright/hmr-issue-minimal-repo, that is roughly how my project is set up:

- `packages/one` is a Yarn workspace containing the backend code
- `packages/two` is a Yarn workspace containing the React
  components/frontend code

If I build this and run it, I can sometimes get it to notice that I'm trying to do a hot reload in the client, fail, and then do a complete page reload. When that happens, the following error appears on the console

```
｢hot｣ Error: Aborted because ../two/renderApp.tsx is not acceptedUpdate propagation: 
../two/renderApp.tsx -> ../two/index.tsx -> ./src/frontend-entry-point.tsx -> 1    at 
hotApplyInternal (http://localhost/assets/app.js:508:30)    at Object.hotApply [as apply] 
(http://localhost/assets/app.js:362:19)    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-hot- 
client/client/hot.js:121:23)
```

I've tried all sorts of different combinations of the various packages and I've also swapped the code that does the hotswap (https://github.com/benwainwright/hmr-issue-minimal-repo/blob/edcd8ad8c4fb9686abce12237d51a5b6f37dd636/packages/two/renderApp.tsx#L13-L16) with **react-hot-loader**. Nothing works. If anyone has *any* idea how to get this working, I'll be eternally greatful!

Comment: What kind of HMR are you looking for? server or client?

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that you need to apply in order for react-hot loader to work.

1. Apply "react-hot-loader/babel" in your babel plugins
2. Make alias of `react-dom` to `@hot-loader/react-dom`
3. Wrap you App root component with `hot` hoc which comes from `react-hot-loader/root`

These steps are basic use-case of React HMR based on https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/master/examples/typescript.

The thing is that your case is a bit more complicated since your front-end app is located in a `node_modules`, and by default babel doesn't compiles modules inside `node_modules`, therefore you need to specify that you want to compile them.

You can read the explanation inside my answer here: [Use Webpack HMR with a hoisted Lerna React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553119/use-webpack-hmr-with-a-hoisted-lerna-react-project/61857082#answer-61857082)